# Ошибка в установке visual studio 2015 enterprise

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Устанавливаю visual studio 2015 enterprise.
И вылетает "стандартная" ошибка, как я понял:

```
Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 : В процессе установки произошла неисправимая ошибка.
Microsoft NuGet - Visual Studio 2015 : Package failed.
Microsoft Visual Studio Connected Services : Package failed.
Azure AD Authentication Connected Service : Package failed.
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Connected Service : Package failed.
Microsoft Azure Storage Connected Service : Package failed.
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Office365 : Package failed.
Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8) - Visual Studio 2015 : Package failed.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть пост на хабре в котором вроде бы все так здорово и понятно:
[Расследование ошибки установки Visual Studio 2015](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/271809/)

В ней говорится что Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86)  на самом деле ставиться x64 версия.

Смотрю какие версии стоят у меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее ищу файл vcruntime140.dll и как видим размер везде разный....
Но как проверить x64 или x86 этот файл я не знаю так как у меня нет студии и соответственно нужных инструментов. Но судя по размеру файлы разного размера и битность скорее всего тоже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как мне исправить эту ошибку? Скину вот еще лон файл, точней конец его

```
=== Logging stopped: 01.01.2017  0:59:42 ===
MSI (s) (60:E4) [00:59:42:344]: Note: 1: 1708 
MSI (s) (60:E4) [00:59:42:344]: Product: Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 -- Installation failed.

MSI (s) (60:E4) [00:59:42:344]: Установщик Windows выполнил установку продукта. Продукт: Team Explorer for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Update 2. Версия: 14.95.25118. Язык: 1033. Изготовитель: Microsoft. Установка завершена с состоянием: 1603.

MSI (s) (60:E4) [00:59:42:345]: Deferring clean up of packages/files, if any exist
MSI (s) (60:E4) [00:59:42:345]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
MSI (s) (60:70) [00:59:42:347]: RESTART MANAGER: Session closed.
MSI (s) (60:70) [00:59:42:347]: No System Restore sequence number for this installation.
MSI (s) (60:70) [00:59:42:347]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (60:70) [00:59:42:348]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (60:70) [00:59:42:348]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (60:70) [00:59:42:348]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (60:70) [00:59:42:348]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\Rollback\Scripts 3: 2 
MSI (s) (60:70) [00:59:42:348]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (B4:94) [00:59:42:349]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (B4:94) [00:59:42:349]: MainEngineThread is returning 1603
=== Verbose logging stopped: 01.01.2017  0:59:42 ===
```

А вот и весь лог: [dd_vs_enterprise_20170101005833_017_vs_teamExplorerCore.log](http://pastebin.com/97M7R0nz)

Comment: Образ сам давно скачивали? Не берусь утверждать, но осмелюсь предположить, что последний образ с встроенным апдейтом №3 уже избавлен от этой ошибки.

Comment: Скачал от сюда: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs

Comment: @CJ1 если вы скачали оттуда - то почему у вас на скриншотах update 2?

Comment: @PashaPash, Я сейчас подробнее расскажу. У меня 7 различных образов студии. У всех ошибки, и такие и другие. Я установил Windows 8.1 на виртуальную машину, и попробовал установить там, и у всех образов на ней различные ошибки. То есть мне сейчас просто целый альбом нужен что бы показывать эти ошибки. Я уже с помощью Procmon отследил что все ошибки связаны с веткой реестра HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Installer\Products\ То есть, по логам я вижу что во время ошибки Windows installer не может найти какое то значения типа 7C9F8B73BF303523781852719CD9C700.

Comment: @CJ1 вы проверяли sha1 образов? может они у вас просто битые? или у вас просто проблемы с диском? или может битая память? т.е. если падает только у вас, но падает сразу все - значит у вас или битый инсталл или битое железо. Локализуйте проблему.

Comment: @CJ1 и, желательно, ограничтесь одним вопросом :(

Comment: @PashaPash Я проверял чек сумы всех образов.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/infopulse/blog/271809/